# Autofill choice(s) disappear or re-appear for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an "autofill" field for a Rails app I've been playing around with for quite some time.  I want to stick to jQuery for this, and for the most part it works pretty well.  However, options will randomly disappear for no clear reason.  I make one Ajax request to the API I'm using (and I'd like to keep it that way) and then remove items that do not match as more characters are typed.  When I search for "Food Chain,"  I type in "food c" and nothing is showing, however... I add the next letter, and the card "Food Chain" appears again.  Here is my codepen if you want to have a look: http://codepen.io/IAMZERG/pen/WxRaBd

HTML:

```
<div class="border">
  <input id="cardsearch" type="text" placeholder="MTG Card Search"></input>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

JS (a little code smell... my apologies):

```
$("#cardsearch").keyup(function (event) {
  //event.preventDefault();
  //$("#results").hide();
  //console.log("button pressed!");
  let inputValue = $(this).val();
  //added if statement. One ajax request to server.  Will filter results
  //if we have already made one.
  //console.log($("#results").html().length);
  if ($("#results").html().length < 1) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards?",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      name: inputValue
    }
  }).done(function (data) {

    data.cards.forEach(function(item) {
      //console.log(item);
      let container = $("#results");
      let result = $("<div class='result'><h2></h2></div>").appendTo(container);
      //console.log(result);
      $("h2:empty").append(item.name)
        .attr("target", "_blank");
      result.append(item.text);
    });

    $(".result").click(function(item) {
      //console.log($(this).find("h2").text());
      $("#cardsearch").val($(this).find("h2").text());
      $("#results").fadeOut();
    });
    //$("#results").append("h1").append(item.title).append(item.snippet);
    //});
    //$("#results").html(data.query.search[5].snippet);
    });
  } else {  //if there are already results, we will filter the results.
    $(".result").each(function (index) {
      console.log($(this).find("h2").text());
      console.log($("#cardsearch").val());
      console.log($(this).find("h2").text().indexOf($("#cardsearch").text()));
      let search = $("#cardsearch").text();
      $(".result").remove(":contains('" + search + "')");
      /*
      if ( $(this).find("h2").text().indexOf($("#cardsearch").val()) === -1) {
        $(this).remove();
      }
      */
    });
    $("#results").show();
  }
});
```

CSS (this is subject to change, and probably will):

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Alef);

input {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  display: block;
  font-family: Alef, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 20px;

  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
     overflow-y: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
     overflow-y: scroll;
}

#results {
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: #99bb99;
  display: block;
  font-family: Alef, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
a:hover {
  color: #999999;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

#results {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.result {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #555;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have always to register event triggers, it's a bad habit.

```
$("#cardsearch").keyup(function (event) {  
  let inputValue = $(this).val();
  if(inputValue.trim()==""){$('#results').empty();return false}
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards?",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      name: inputValue
    }
  }).done(function (data) {
    let container = $("#results");
    container.empty();
    data.cards.forEach(function(item) {
      //simple ? 
      let result = $("<div class='result'><h2></h2></div>");
      result.children('h2').first().append(item.name);
      result.append(item.text);
      result.attr("targer","_blank");
      container.append(result);
       });
    });


});
//register one event for result click
$("#results").on('click','.result',function(){
      //console.log($(this).find("h2").text());
      $("#cardsearch").val($(this).find("h2").text());
});
```

Here is enhancement, it calls it every 2 seconds :)

```
var allowed=true;
var timeoutHandler = null;
$("#cardsearch").keyup(function (event) {
  //event.preventDefault();
  //$("#results").hide();
  //console.log("button pressed!");

  let inputValue = $(this).val();
  //added if statement. One ajax request to server.  Will filter results
  //if we have already made one.
  //console.log($("#results").html().length);
 if(inputValue.trim()==""){$('#results').empty();return false;}
 if(!allowed){clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);timeoutHandler=setTimeout(function(){$('#cardsearch').keyup()},1000);return false};
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards?",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      name: inputValue
    }
  }).done(function (data) {
    allowed = false;
    let container = $("#results");
    container.empty();
    setTimeout(function(){allowed=true;},1800);
    data.cards.forEach(function(item) {
      //console.log(item);
      let result = $("<div class='result'><h2></h2></div>");
      result.children('h2').first().append(item.name);
      result.append(item.text);
      result.attr("targer","_blank");
      container.append(result);
       });
    });
    $("#results").on('click','.result',function(){
      //console.log($(this).find("h2").text());
      $("#cardsearch").val($(this).find("h2").text());
    });

});
```

Comment: Duly noted.  Adjustment made.  I would still prefer not making an API request for every letter entered.  Might implement the cached pattern shown in the jQuery UI autocomplete example in their docs..  Thanks for the help

Comment: Well you can actually avoid it by using `if(inputValue.length < 3) return false` so it will wait until user eners at least 3 chars, or you could set timeout if you wish.

Comment: That will work, friend.  This will not be the only field on the page, but if it is querying for 3 or more characters at a time, it should not overload the API with requests.  Where it is used, there will probably be about 15-25 of these with styling and HTML that's a little prettier, and an awful lot smaller.  If all else fails, StackOverflow :)